# Connecting to an HTTPS server with boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, https, boost-asio

I want to connect to an HTTPS server using boost::asio. I managed to successfully shake hands with the server, but I just can't manage to get the server to respond to my POST request.

This is the related code (I left out debugging and try-catch to save some space):

```
HTTPSClient::HTTPSClient()
{
    ssl::context context(ssl::context::sslv23);
    context.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    context.set_default_verify_paths();
    context.load_verify_file("certificate.pem");
    mSSLSocket = new ssl::stream<ip::tcp::socket>(mIOService, context);
}
```

```
void HTTPSClient::SendRequest(const ptree &crPTree, const std::string cHost, 
    const std::string cURI)
{
    tcp::resolver resolver(mIOService);
    tcp::resolver::query query(cHost, "https");
    resolver.async_resolve(query, boost::bind(&HTTPSClient::HandleResolve, this, 
        placeholders::error, placeholders::iterator, request));
}
```

```
void HTTPSClient::HandleResolve(const error_code &crError, 
    const iterator &criEndpoints, HTTPSRequest &rRequest)
{
    async_connect(mSSLSocket->lowest_layer(), criEndpoints, 
        boost::bind(&HTTPSClient::HandleConnect, this, placeholders::error, 
        rRequest));
}
```

```
void HTTPSClient::HandleConnect(const error_code &crError, HTTPSRequest &rRequest)
{
    mSSLSocket->lowest_layer().set_option(ip::tcp::no_delay(true));
    mSSLSocket->set_verify_callback(ssl::rfc2818_verification(rRequest.mcHost));
    mSSLSocket->handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);

    // Write the json into a stringstream
    std::ostringstream json;
    boost::property_tree::write_json(json, rRequest.mcPTree);
    std::string result;
    result = json.str();

    // Form the request
    streambuf request;
    std::ostream requestStream(&request);
    requestStream << "POST " << rRequest.mcURI << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    requestStream << "Host: " << rRequest.mcHost << "\r\n";
    requestStream << "Accept: application/json\r\n";
    requestStream << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    requestStream << "Content-Length: " << result.length() << "\r\n";
    requestStream << result << "\r\n\r\n";

    write(*mSSLSocket, request);

    streambuf response;
    read_until(*mSSLSocket, response, "\r\n");
    std::istream responseStream(&response);
}
```

read_until hangs until it throws the error read_until: End of file. Everything before that goes successfully, including the SSL handshake (which I just recently figured out).

I used to do everything asynchronously until I started debugging, and started trying to backtrace to the problem, to no avail. It would be awesome if someone could help me out after two painful days of debugging.

EDIT
I just realized it might be useful to add the contents of requestStream after composing the header:

```
POST /authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: <hostname>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 136
{
    "username": "vijfhoek",
    "password": "test123",
    <other json content>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out what I was doing wrong. For some reason, I couldn't get boost to write data using the boost::asio::streambuf and std::ostream approach. Instead, I put the POST data in a std::string and sent it like this:

```
write(*mSSLSocket, boost::asio::buffer(requestString));
```

Which worked out fine.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to set the streams to binary and `noskipws`

Answer (score 6):

You need a double linefeed before the body (POST contents)

```
POST /authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: <hostname>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 136

{
    "username": "vijfhoek",
    "password": "test123",
    <other json content>
}
```

Otherwise, the content will have been received by the server as *header lines* and the server just keeps waiting for `136` bytes of content data (also make sure that Content-Length is accurate, which it isn't in this example)

So, basically:

```
requestStream << "Content-Length: " << result.length() << "\r\n";
requestStream << "\r\n"; // THIS LINE ADDED
```

Comment: That `\r\n\r\n` ending is also unnecessary. (unless it's actually part of the body, that is)

Comment: That sadly did not help, I still can't get an answer from the server. The Content-Length is accurate, too, but I left out some json data in the question.

Comment: @vijfhoek Use fiddler (or some other kind of sniffing tool) to inspect the traffic. Check the content-length. Consider adding a 'Connection: Close' header. Basically: debug things or post a new question ***with SSCCE**. This was the error in the code shown.

Comment: I have done my debugging. I used a browser plug-in to look at how my browser does it when trying to communicate with the server, and I exactly reproduced the headers. I tried throwing the exact same string at the server as my browser did, to no avail. Also, considering it's HTTPS, it's really hard to use sniffing tools to examine the problem.